# AWS ec2 instance stops every 3rd day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, amazon-route53

i have an ec2 instance running on AWS.. it runs only for 2 or 3 days.. after that i get status check error 'Instance reachability check failed'. i dont understand why it is happening. can someone help me with this issue. and just for reference node server puppeteer along with some api call. Usual api call to server could take aorund 10-35 second due to the parallel calls it makes inside the node api.
and following i am sharing some system logs that received at the end

```
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRemove Stale Onliâ¦ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mAccounts Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mA high performanceâ¦er and a reverse proxy server[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mModem Manager[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDisk Manager[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mLogin Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mUnattended Upgrades Shutdown[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mHostname Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mEC2 Instance Connect Host Key Harvesting[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mOpenBSD Secure Shell server[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mOpenBSD Secure Shell server[0m.


Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS ip-172-31-26-38 ttyS0

ip-172-31-26-38 login: [   30.308818] cloud-init[1458]: Cloud-init v. 23.1.2-0ubuntu0~20.04.2 running 'modules:config' at Mon, 09 Oct 2023 12:49:22 +0000. Up 30.17 seconds.
[   31.169166] cloud-init[1465]: Cloud-init v. 23.1.2-0ubuntu0~20.04.2 running 'modules:final' at Mon, 09 Oct 2023 12:49:23 +0000. Up 30.97 seconds.
[   31.169317] cloud-init[1465]: Cloud-init v. 23.1.2-0ubuntu0~20.04.2 finished at Mon, 09 Oct 2023 12:49:23 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up 31.16 seconds
```

i tried making changes to ec2 security groups.

[image: security roups]

Comment: It sounds like the server is crashing. You need to be looking at the CPU and RAM usage to see if those are maxing out right before these issues happen. Also, if it is a t* instance type,  you need to be looking at the CPU credits to see if they are being exhausted.